# How to create for loop with delay to display a message every X seconds?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a function that takes the array contents and display each element (text),
I'm using swiftUI @State variable to store the message, I've also tried environment object variables to store the messages and display them in a Text(""). Currently The function only Displays the last message in the array, it only stores the ending loop element in the array.

Please let me know how can I display each message with a delay at a time

Thanks

```
@State var messages = ["Welcome","FirstName","LastName"]
@State var message = ""

func DisplayMessageAnimation(messages: [String]) {


    for i in 0..<messages.count {

        // your code here
        self.message = messages[i]
        print(" message", self.message)

        sleep(UInt32(5.0))
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a repeating timer which you can cancel if the view disappears.

E.g. to rotate through the strings:

```
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message = "Hello, world!"
    @State var timer: AnyCancellable?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(message)
            Button(action: {
                self.startRepeatingRotation(with: ["foo", "bar", "baz"])
            }) {
                Text("Start rotating messages")
            }
        }.onDisappear {
            self.timer?.cancel()
        }
    }

    private func startRepeatingRotation(with messages: [String]) {
        guard !messages.isEmpty else { return }

        var index = 0
        self.message = messages[0]
        self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().sink { output in
            index = (index + 1) % messages.count
            self.message = messages[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted it to stop when it got to the end of the sequence, i.e. a non-repeating sequence, perhaps:

```
private func startRotation(with messages: [String]) {
    guard !messages.isEmpty else { return }

    var index = 0
    self.message = messages[0]
    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().sink { output in
        index += 1
        guard index < messages.count else {
            self.timer?.cancel()
            return
        }
        self.message = messages[index]
    }
}
```

---

FWIW,

- Never “sleep”. You never want to block the main thread.
- You shouldn’t use `asyncAfter` either. If you do, those scheduled dispatches will stay out there, waiting to run, even if you dismiss the view in question. And if the time intervals are far out in the future, you’ll start to see “coalescing” of these separate `asyncAfter` calls, not running them every five seconds like you wanted.

Comment: Timers are a poor advice. But yes you can improve asynch call with weak self, and scheduling only 1 next execution.

Comment: Repeating timers are designed precisely for situations like this where you want some task to be repeated at some regular interval.

Answer (score -3):

I thinks it goes like this

```
for i in items {
do {
    sleep(4)
   }
   // Your code here
}
```